# Why is $\lim_{x\to a}{[f(x)\cdot g(x)]}=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}$, but $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$

Tags: limits, derivatives

For example the limit of 2 functions multiplied together is a straightforward equivalent of the multiplication of each function separately limited:
$$\lim_{x\to a}{[f(x)\cdot g(x)]}=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)}$$ 
but not so with derivatives. The product rule requires: $$(fg)'=f'g +
 fg'$$
How can this be?

Comment: The derivative is the limit of the difference quotient, not the limit of $fg$.

Comment: It simply isn't the case that $\frac {f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)(g(x)}h=\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h\times \frac {g(x+h)-g(x)}h$ even in the limit.  Why should it?

Comment: I like to recommend that we should never ask why something *isn’t* true, because in general, in mathematics, *nothing* is true, *unless there is a proof that it’s true*.

Comment: I have long wondered about this phenomenon of people wondering why something in mathematics isn't true and thinking that everything in mathematics should be presumed true until proved false.

Comment: Because God wants us to be truth seekers, rather than purveyors of disinformation and what better subject to seek truth in than mathematics? ESPECIALLY IN TODAY'S WORLD! As a matter of fact, I did find my answer: the limit calculations refer back to the difference quotient function of the original function whereas the derivative calculations refer back to the original function itself. Two different things. Will post more detail later. By being curious, we understand the world better.

Comment: Basically, what Elliot G pointed out, which I didn't understand at first but after quite a bit of playing around with it, I now do. Thanks Elliot! I am very grateful for this site and for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $fg$ is not a product of limits of $f$ and $g$. Recall that 
$$f'(x) = \lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$$
So using our result for the limit of a product would give us
\begin{align*}
f'(x)g'(x) =& \bigg[\lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}\bigg] \cdot \bigg[\lim_{y \to x} \frac{g(y) - g(x)}{y-x} \bigg]\\ \neq& \lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)g(y) - f(x)g(x)}{x-y} = (fg)'(x)
\end{align*}
in general.

Answer (score 1):

These are limits of different things, and there is no reason to expect $(fg)'$ to be $f'g'$. In fact, there is, a priori, not even a reason to expect the first relation that you wrote down to be true, it requires rigorous proof (which, if you are learning this in school, you were probably not given).

Does the following example help you? The limit $\lim_{x\to a}\left((f(x)-5)(g(x)-5)\right)$ is certainly not equal to $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x)-5)$, so you cannot always expect to be able to pull products into limits in a simple minded way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a derivative is a limit.
And, yes, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

But the derivative is something a little bit more complicated than what you suggest.

$\frac {d}{dx} f(x) = f'(x) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

$\frac {d}{dx} f(x)g(x) = $$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h)g(x+h) -f(x+h)g(x) +f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h)(g(x+h) -g(x)) +(f(x+h) - f(x))g(x)}{h}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0} f(x+h)\frac {g(x+h) -g(x)}{h} +  \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}g(x)\\
f(x) g'(x) + f'(x)g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how we multiply fractions.

The derivative of $f(x)$ at a point $x=a$ is $$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
The derivative of $g(x)$ at the same point is
$$g'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$$

If you multiplied the first two expressions together you'd get
$$f'(a)g'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\left(f(x)-f(a)\right)\left(g(x)-g(a) \right)}{(x-a)^2}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(x)-g(a)f(x)+f(a)g(a)}{(x-a)^2}$$

However, this is *not* the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ at $x=a$.  That would be given by

$$(fg)'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)}{x-a}$$

You can see that the expression for $f'(a)g'(a)$ has extra unwanted terms in the numerator, the wrong sign on the last term in the numerator, and the wrong power of $(x-a)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple model just based on products, which may help you to understand. Note that $$(x+p)(y+q)=xy+xq+py+pq$$ so that $$(x+p)(y+q)-xy=xq+py+pq$$

Here we can see how the change in the product (and therefore the derivative of the product) is related to the cross terms in the product - if $p$ and $q$ are both small, their product will be insignificant.